# How to request with nested json in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to send the nested object to the server with authorization token, I searched for this issue but not getting a solution from any sites

***This is how I send Data:***

```
CallUpdateProfile = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token', (err, token) => {
        tokenAuth = token
     });
     AsyncStorage.getItem('userId', (err, userID) => {

         UserID = userID

      });
 const insideData={
          userId : UserID,
          contactparam :{
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
          cellPhoneNumber: this.state.cellPhoneNumber,
      }

};
console.log(insideData);
    updateProfile(insideData)
      .then(response => {
        let data = response.data.data;     
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }
```

***but result is***

```
{
  "contactparam": {
    "firstName": "DK2",
    "lastName": "KHATRI",
    "emailAddress": "abc@hmail.com",
    "cellPhoneNumber": "9999999990"
  }
}
```

***what is the expected result ?***

```
userId: 1,
 {
  "contactparam": {
    "firstName": "DK2",
    "lastName": "KHATRI",
    "emailAddress": "abc@hmail.com",
    "cellPhoneNumber": "9999999990"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code insideData object create before AsyncStorage fetch userId. So make CallUpdateProfile as async & wait until AsyncStorage fetch userId as below.

```
CallUpdateProfile = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.getItem("token", (err, token) => {
    tokenAuth = token;
  });
  await AsyncStorage.getItem("userId", (err, userID) => {
    UserID = userID;
  });
  const insideData = {
    userId: UserID,
    contactparam: {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
      cellPhoneNumber: this.state.cellPhoneNumber
    }
  };
  console.log(insideData);
  updateProfile(insideData)
    .then(response => {
      let data = response.data.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to archive the desired object

```
CallUpdateProfile = async () => {
      const UserID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
      if (UserID !== null) {
        const insideData = {
            userId: UserID,
            contactparam: {
                firstName: this.state.firstName,
                lastName: this.state.lastName,
                emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
                cellPhoneNumber: this.state.cellPhoneNumber,
            }
        }
            // continue you implentation

     }
};
```